# How do I get ethernet cable to register on the network?

Tags: windows-7, networking, ethernet

I have been using an ethernet cable on my personal Windows 7 x64 laptop to my corporate network at work. I unplugged it one day, then plugged it back in the next day, I didn't even use the laptop between the times I unplugged/plugged-in but I cannot register on the network ? It keeps saying "Identifying". I've tried ipconfig/release and /renew with no change. I have tried disabling other network adapters and still no luck. How can I get a connection on an ethernet cable that had worked only the day before ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the network is perpetually "unidentified", it can be caused by Windows security policy's treatment of the connection as "public". You may have inadvertently set this the first time you connected, but I can't be sure.

You can try and set the connection as "work" or "home" but you may not even get this option if the network adapter is still trying to automatically obtain an IP address. You can however force windows to accept the connection as "Work" after which your computer will then get dns/dhcp connection and assign an ip address.

You can force Windows to accept the "unidentified" connection by using a powershell script I found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dimeby8/archive/2009/06/10/change-unidentified-network-from-public-to-work-in-windows-7.aspx). I have re-printed it below in case the link disappears. Steps are:

1/ Create this script in a file like c:\temp\SetWorkNetworkType_work.ps1

```
# 
# 
# This script can be used to change the network category of 
# an 'Unidentified' network to Private to allow common network 
# activity. This script should only be run when connected to 
# a network that is trusted since it will also affect the 
# firewall profile used. 
# This script is provided as-is and Microsoft does not assume any 
# liability. This script may be redistributed as long as the file 
# contains these terms of use unmodified. 
# 
# Usage: 
# Start an elevated Powershell command window and execute 
# SetWorkNetworkType_work.ps1
#  
$NLMType = [Type]::GetTypeFromCLSID('DCB00C01-570F-4A9B-8D69-199FDBA5723B')
$INetworkListManager = [Activator]::CreateInstance($NLMType)

$NLM_ENUM_NETWORK_CONNECTED  = 1
$NLM_NETWORK_CATEGORY_PUBLIC = 0x00
$NLM_NETWORK_CATEGORY_PRIVATE = 0x01
$UNIDENTIFIED = "Unidentified network"

$INetworks = $INetworkListManager.GetNetworks($NLM_ENUM_NETWORK_CONNECTED)

foreach ($INetwork in $INetworks)
{
    $Name = $INetwork.GetName()
    $Category = $INetwork.GetCategory()

    if ($INetwork.IsConnected -and ($Category -eq $NLM_NETWORK_CATEGORY_PUBLIC) -and ($Name -eq $UNIDENTIFIED))
    {
        $INetwork.SetCategory($NLM_NETWORK_CATEGORY_PRIVATE)
    }
}
```

2/ Update the execution policy for your session (select "y" when prompted)

PS> set-executionpolicy remotesigned

3/ Run the script

PS> c:\temp\SetWorkNetworkType_work.ps1

If you check your network connection from "Network and Sharing" it should now list the "unidentified network" as "Network *2*" "Work Network" 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are talking about your laptop at home, did you check if your router is online?

It could be that DHCP on your laptop is unable to find a DHCP server.  If your router/cable modem/etc. (whatever device you use to connect to your ISP) is offline, or your ISP is down, you might not be able to get a connection depending on your exact topography.

Comment: No. This problem relates to using a Windows 7 laptop in a corporate environment. I have updated my question to reflect this.